# I'm using jasmine 1.3. Why is my jasmine test page showing 1.2?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a Rails project [testing its Javascripts using Jasmine](http://www.flashesofpanic.com/panic/002611.php). (The link describes the setup, which is roughly `jasmine`, `jasmine-jquery-rails`, and `guard-jasmine`.) I recently ran `bundle update` and wound up with these versions in my `Gemfile.lock` file:

```
guard-jasmine (1.18.3)
[...]
jasmine (1.3.2)
  jasmine-core (~> 1.3.1)
  [...]
jasmine-ajax (0.0.2)
jasmine-core (1.3.1)
jasmine-jquery-rails (1.5.9)
jasminerice (0.0.10)
  coffee-rails
  haml
```

Now, `guard-jasmine` starts a jasmine server on a local port. When I visit this I get a jasmine test page not unlike that [at the bottom of the Jasmine project page](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Downloads). However, the top of that page says, "Jasmine 1.2.0 revision 1337005947".

If I open the gem files at `bundle show jasmine-core` and look at `jasmine.js` I definitely have 1.3.1, but the version being loaded by the test runner is definitely 1.2.0. How can I figure out where the old version is coming from, and ask it to use the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching across all the gems, I determined that `jasminerice` is responsible for serving an older version of Jasmine. By pulling `jasminerice` [directly from Github](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) I was able to get a more current version of Jasmine in the test runner. I'd like a way to use the version in `jasmine-core` instead (isn't that why it's installed?) but for now this will do.